# How can I use pinch zoom without calling my swipe function in webview?

Tags: android, webview, swipe, gesture, pinchzoom

When I use the pinch zoom gesture, in a horizontal way, the swipe function is always called when it reached a certain difference of the pressed coordinates and the released coordinates.

How can I fix this?

This are the settings for the webview

```
    view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    view.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 
    view.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

The swipe function

```
    protected void swipePage(View v, MotionEvent event, int book) {
    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

    switch (action) {
    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
        swipeOriginX = event.getX();
        swipeOriginY = event.getY();
        break;

    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
        int quarterWidth = (int) (screenWidth * 0.3);
        float diffX = swipeOriginX - event.getX();
        float diffY = swipeOriginY - event.getY();
        float absDiffX = Math.abs(diffX);
        float absDiffY = Math.abs(diffY);

        if ((diffX > quarterWidth) && (absDiffX > absDiffY)) {
            try {
                navigator.goToNextChapter(index);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                errorMessage(getString(R.string.error_cannotTurnPage));
            }
        } else if ((diffX < -quarterWidth) && (absDiffX > absDiffY)) {
            try {
                navigator.goToPrevChapter(index);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                errorMessage(getString(R.string.error_cannotTurnPage));
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check if this work - put a if condition checking if single finger touch is there then only do the swipe. change "event" variable to your local variable.

```
 if(event.getPointerCount() == 1)
  {
    switch (action) {
     case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
          swipeOriginX = event.getX();
          swipeOriginY = event.getY();
           break;

    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):

    int quarterWidth = (int) (screenWidth * 0.3);
    float diffX = swipeOriginX - event.getX();
    float diffY = swipeOriginY - event.getY();
    float absDiffX = Math.abs(diffX);
    float absDiffY = Math.abs(diffY);

    if ((diffX > quarterWidth) && (absDiffX > absDiffY)) {
        x = 1;
        try {
            navigator.goToNextChapter(index);
            x = 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            x = 1;
            errorMessage(getString(R.string.error_cannotTurnPage));
        }
    } else if ((diffX < -quarterWidth) && (absDiffX > absDiffY)) {
        x = 1;
        try {
            navigator.goToPrevChapter(index);
            x = 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            x = 1;
            errorMessage(getString(R.string.error_cannotTurnPage));
        }


    break;    
    }
  }
}
else if(event.getPointerCount()==2)
 {
   // code for pinch zoom
 }
```

Comment: it's not working.. the pinch zoom that I am using the built in codes for the WebView. I just enabled the pinch zoom function in the settings of my WebView.